# NG0304: 'app-create-community-menu' is not a known element (used in the 'CommunityListComponent' component template):

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to make unit test for my angular component but I keep getting errors about the html. For example that he doesnt know the app-create component in the test. This is for every test in every component. Even if I just want to check if 0 equals 0.
Does anyone know a fix for this? or how to stop getting HTML errors

My test code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CommunityListComponent } from './community-list.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Community } from '../../../models/domain/Community';
import { CommunityService } from '../../../services/API/community.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../../services/common.service';

describe('CommunityListComponent', () => {
  let component: CommunityListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CommunityListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [CommunityListComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CommunityListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Ewa', () => {
    expect(0).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class which defines `app-create-community-menu` into the `imports` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Matthieu suggests or you can use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` by doing the following:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
describe('CommunityListComponent', () => {
  let component: CommunityListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CommunityListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [CommunityListComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CommunityListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Ewa', () => {
    expect(0).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

`NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` says if you find anything in HTML you don't know how to render, treat is as dead HTML.